# Ruby How to trim this simple code down?

Tags: ruby, performance

I just need the following logic to run once since this is going to be put inside a loop. I'm overwhelmed by many variables and methods that I've declared, so this will speed up my debugging speed on individual level.

```
$just_once = 1 if $just_once.nil?
if $just_once == 1
  p "Its PASSING!!"
  $just_once = 2
end
```

Methinks 5 lines is too much. There should be ways to cut it down to only 2-3 lines or even 1.

Comment: Trimming line count is easy, but that doesn't mean it will be faster. All the solutions below do exactly the same operations underneath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
(p "it's passing"; $just_once = true) if (!$just_once)
"it's passing"
=> true

(p "it's passing"; $just_once = true) if (!$just_once)
=> nil
```

Comment: brilliant! So it is possible to trim down to 1 line.

Answer (score 2):

This is not as short as the other answers but this is how I would code it to maintain readability:

```
if $just_once.nil? || $just_once == 1
  p "Its PASSING!!"
  $just_once = 2
end
```

---

For academic interest, here is a one-liner:

```
p "Its PASSING!!" and $just_once = 2 if $just_once.nil? || $just_once == 1
```

(Tin Man, please forgive my sins :)

---

Lastly, based on comments with mu is too short:

```
p "Its PASSING!!" and $just_once = true if !$just_once
```

Comment: Well, thanks for the participation. I'm going to delete the code once I'm done with them though, so readibility is not a concern. :P

Comment: Readability should always be a concern. The internet is running on top of "hey, I wonder if this works?" code, that *should* have been thrown away, or refactored, but nobody was ever given the chance. So always write as if your code will be used forever.

Comment: @theTinMan: Today's quick hack is tomorrow's mission critical application that supports the entire business. Over and over and over again.

Comment: Definitely so. So many times I have had to maintain other people's hacks, and to wrangle them into some sort of supportable form; I've cussed and sworn at their decisions. And, I'm very proud to say, people who've inherited my code have told me how much they appreciated that my code was readable and well documented, which was nice to hear.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
$just_once = 1 if $just_once.nil?
p "Its PASSING!!" if $just_once == 1 && $just_once += 1
```

Not sure what for though since you didn't explain what your end goal is.

Answer (score 1):

Do as below

```
$just_once ||= 1
p "Its PASSING!!" if $just_once == 1 && $just_once += 1
```

**update** as @the Tin Man told.

```
$just_once ||= 1
if $just_once == 1
   p "Its PASSING!!"
   $just_once += 1
end
```

Comment: You forgot the global sign. I tried this and it's looping like crazy since the variable got deleted and recreated in a loop. Deigo got it, but methinks you have a better syntax with that ||= operator. :D

Comment: Haha, yea, I need to wait about 2-3 minutes, before putting the 'check' mark. That 'if' statement with the combination of '&&' operator just blow my mind. Didn't know it's possible. :D

Comment: Don't chain `if $just_once == 1 && $just_once += 1`. An `if` should only test a condition. `$just_once += 1` should occur inside the block.

Comment: @theTinMan You want me to put the `$just_once += 1` inside `if cond .. end` block.

Comment: @Matt I did it as tinman suggested.. as an example OP mentioned that *if `nil` then assign `1`*, but in real case that could not be, so The line `$just_once += 1` makes sense. Anyway, holds the both now my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Convenient truths:

1. `nil.to_i` is zero.
2. `1.to_i` is `1`.
3. Globals are auto-vivified on first access just like instance variables.
4. `==` is quite happy to compare `nil` and `1`.

That allows you to hide the conditional logic behind a `to_i` call:

```
if $just_once == 1
   p "Its PASSING!!"
   $just_once = $just_once.to_i + 1
end
```

Another convenient truth is that `nil` is falsey so you could use a boolean instead of a counter:

```
if !$been_here_already
   p "Its PASSING!!"
   $been_here_already = true
end
```

Comment: Isn't it more readable to simply have `$just_once = 2` in the `if` block? When would it ever be otherwise?

Comment: @Matt: On second though I'd probably go straight to a boolean instead of counting things: `if !$been_here_already ....`

Comment: Good point. This can be condensed to `$been_here_already = true and p "It's PASSING!!" if !$been_here_already`

Comment: @Matt: *can* and *should* are different words :) There's no good reason to prefer cleverness over readability.